# Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:81' (0) in CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, mamp

I am using mamp instead of xamp. In that the localhost configured to port number 81. For mysql it is 3307.

For my case I cannot use the ports 80 and 3306. In database.php of configure in CodeIgniter, how can I specify the host details? If I put localhost:81, it shows the  Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:81' (0). If I give localhost, it takes the localhost:80 to find the db. but I want it to take the db in localhost:81.

Comment: Can you update your question with a sanitised config file please.Otherwise this question will likely get closed as insufficient context, and not helpful to any returning users.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: did you change your localhost in `php.ini`, please post you `php.ini` localhost config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know your mysql port is 3307 just add localhost:3307 or 127.0.0.1:3307 in the database.php of your codeigniter setup. localhost:81 is for your application server. Use that in browser to browse your app.